# Azure Function app REST Api with Table Storage and SignalR

Tags: azure, rest, signalr, azure-functions

I have looked at the various questions posted on Table Storage and SignalR in StackOverflow, but none have demonstrated how an Azure function app works with Table Storage and SignalR together.

I have built two Azure Function apps one with REST Api and Table Storage with the below mentioned Project References (note the version number too)

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.23" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After adding SignalR package the basic negotiate and messages Functions compile fine but are unregistered on run.

On the contrary with the Table Storage and only signalR with below Project reference just works fine

```
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

For some reason I am not able to use SDK functions version 3.0.* to get to work with Table Storage.
Can somebody please suggest me with a PackageReference that caters both **SignalR** and **Table Storage** for Azure Function apps.

This comes close to answering my question
[SignalRCore and Azure functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58720675/signalrcore-and-azure-functions)
but here Azure Functions are not used.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is "After adding SignalR package the basic negotiate and messages Functions compile fine but are unregistered on run."?

Comment: Could you please tell me the error message when you use SDK functions version 3.0.* to get to work with Table Storage?